# Parse HTML Data Using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to create a table where the ff. will show but I got some problems

```
    public class Book
    {
        public HtmlAttribute Href{ get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public string Author{ get; set; }
        public string Characters{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is the page I am trying to parse, I need the **href value,** the **link**, the **description** and the **character list** (*sometimes there is none*):

```
    <div id=title> 
        <li>
            <h3><a href="www.harrypotter.com">Harry Potter</a></h3>
            <div>Harry James Potter is the title character of J. K. Rowling's Harry Potter series. </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Harry Potter</li>
                <li>Hermione Granger</li>
                <li>Ron Weasley</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3><a href="www.littleprince.com">Little Prince</a></h3>
            <div>A little girl lives in a very grown-up world with her mother, who tries to prepare her for it.  </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

And this is my code to parse it and put it in a list

```
    List<Book> BookList= new List<Book>();
    var titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"title\"]//li//h3");
    var descNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"title\"]//li//div");
    var authorNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"title\"]//li//ul");

    var title = titleNode.Select(node => node.InnerText).ToList();
    var desc = descNode.Select(node => node.InnerText).ToList();
    var characters= authorNode.Select(node => node.InnerText).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < Title.Count(); ++i)
    {
        var list= new Book();
        list.Title= title[i];
        list.Author= desc[i];
        list.Characters = characters[i];
        BookList.Add(list);
    }
```

My questions are: 1) How will I get the href value and add it in the list? 2) Some have no  tag for characters in the html, how can I get the list without an NullReferenceException error? Note: I can't make any changes in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve your problem without using HTMLAgilityPack, Here I am using 
System.Xml

Note: You should add some unique values to identify Main **li** element, Here I have added Class as 'Main'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test
{
public class Book
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Characters { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str="<div id='title'><li class='Main'><h3><a href='www.harrypotter.com'>Harry Potter</a></h3><div>Harry James Potter is the title character of J. K. Rowling's Harry Potter series. </div>";
        str += "<ul><li>Harry Potter</li><li>Hermione Granger</li><li>Ron Weasley</li></ul></li><li class='Main'><h3><a href='www.littleprince.com'>Little Prince</a></h3><div>A little girl lives in a very grown-up world with her mother, who tries to prepare her for it.  </div></li></div>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(str);

        XmlNodeList xnList= doc.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"title\"]//li[@class=\"Main\"]");

        List<Book> BookList=new List<Book>();

        for (int i = 0; i < xnList.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode TitleNode = xnList[i].SelectSingleNode("h3");
            XmlNode DescNode = xnList[i].SelectSingleNode("div");
            XmlNode AuthorNode = xnList[i].SelectSingleNode("ul");

            Book list = new Book();
            if(TitleNode!=null)
                list.Title=TitleNode.InnerText;
            else
                list.Title="";

            if (DescNode != null)
                list.Author = DescNode.InnerText;
            else
                list.Author = string.Empty;

            if (AuthorNode != null)
                list.Characters = AuthorNode.InnerText;
            else
                list.Characters = string.Empty;

            if (TitleNode != null && TitleNode.ChildNodes.Count>0)
            {
                XmlNode HrefNode = TitleNode.ChildNodes[0];
                if (HrefNode != null && HrefNode.Attributes.Count > 0 && HrefNode.Attributes["href"] != null)
                    list.Href = HrefNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
                else
                    list.Href = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                list.Href = string.Empty;
            }

            BookList.Add(list);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the html because it is from the website I am trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do. Let me know your questions so I could help.

```
        //get all li(s)
        var lis = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Where(_ => _.ParentNode.Id.Equals("title"));
        foreach (var li in lis)
        {
            //get tile and href
            var title = li.Descendants("h3").FirstOrDefault().InnerText; //you can check null or empty here
            var href = li.Descendants("h3").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name.Equals("a"))?.Attributes["href"]; //again check null here
            var desc = li.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault().InnerHtml;
            var characters = li.Descendants("ul").FirstOrDefault()?.Descendants("li");
            foreach (var character in characters)
            {
                var val = character.InnerText;
            }
        }
```